# Remove the suffix " - Dolphin" from the Dolphin title bar

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin

In Kubuntu, if I have a Dolphin window open in the Home folder, the title bar reads "Home - Dolphin".  Can I change this to just read "Home"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Dolphin options**

```
:~$ dolphin --help

Usage: dolphin [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [options] [Url] 

File Manager

Generic options:
  --help                    Show help about options
  --help-qt                 Show Qt specific options
  --help-kde                Show KDE specific options
  --help-all                Show all options
  --author                  Show author information
  -v, --version             Show version information
  --license                 Show license information
  --                        End of options

Options:
  --select                  The files and directories passed as arguments will be selected.
  --split                   Dolphin will get started with a split view.

Arguments:
  Url                       Document to open
```

The Qt options has:

> --title            sets the application title (caption)

[image]

With the KDE menu editor you could set the Dolphin start command - http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/kmenuedit/

**----EDIT----**

The KDE 4.10 and later supports the scripted title manipulation / stripping.

Feature request: http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=111&t=110113 . Bug/wish: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=308995

Tested with the KDE 4.11:

Backup the files before you edit them ;)

Editing the /usr/share/kde4/apps/kwin/stripTitle.js and adding the Dolphin to the list.

[image]

Enabling the tittle manipulation by running the command:

```
kwriteconfig --file kwinrc --group Windows --key CondensedTitle true
```

It will add a line to the kwinrc

[image]

More of the kwriteconfig:

```
:~$ kwriteconfig --help
Usage: kwriteconfig [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [options] value 

Write KConfig entries - for use in shell scripts

Generic options:
  --help                    Show help about options
  --help-qt                 Show Qt specific options
  --help-kde                Show KDE specific options
  --help-all                Show all options
  --author                  Show author information
  -v, --version             Show version information
  --license                 Show license information
  --                        End of options

Options:
  --file <file>             Use <file> instead of global config
  --group <group>           Group to look in. Use repeatedly for nested groups. [KDE]
  --key <key>               Key to look for
  --type <type>             Type of variable. Use "bool" for a boolean, otherwise it is treated as a string

Arguments:
  value                     The value to write. Mandatory, on a shell use '' for empty
```

Rebooting - at here the Dolphin title is only showing the directory information.

Comment: Good info to have, but I'm not sure it works 100%.  (1) launching application manually with a title from command line, the title changes whenever I navigate away from current folder and (2) the KDE menu editor does not seem to work, even when I add the options to the command line there, the GUI launch of Dolphin comes up with normal title.

Comment: For some reason I missed your edits.  The stripTitle.js does indeed work in 4.11!  So it does answer my question, but unfortunately a few issues remain.  (1) Long title still shows in task manager (smooth tasks) titles and (2) Not possible pre 4.10 (I'm forced to use 4.8 on some certain computers).  Thanks anyway though for an answer which admittedly does solve the posted question! :-)